# Implode an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array();
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {   

        $rray = array(
            'name'=>$item['name'],
            'qty'=>$item['qty']
        );
        $array[] = $rray; 

        }           

}
```

I have the array like the above
How to create a string look like this:
'name qty, name qty, name qty, name qty, name qty, name qty, name qty,  '

'Afghan Kush 1, Pomegranate Blue-Rasp 1, Blueberry Vanilla 1, Banana Strawberry 1, Caramel Cappuccino 1, '

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: dat Blackberry Kush tho...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$array_text = implode(', ', array_map(function ($e) { return $e['name'] . ' ' . $e['qty']; }, $array));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mystring = "";    

foreach($array as $strain) {
    $strain['array_text'] = $strain['name']." ".$strain['qty'];
    $mystring .= $strain['array_text'].", ";
}

echo $mystrain;
```

Comment: When I use this function:

Comment: foreach($rray as $key => $value) {
   $result .= "$key $value";
   $result .= ", ";
   $array_ingredients =  implode(', ', $result);
  }

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$array = [
    [
        'name' => 'Blackberry Kush',
        'qty' => '1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Granddaddy Purple',
        'qty' => '1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => '20% THC',
        'qty' => '1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Pomegranate Blue-Rasp',
        'qty' => '1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Blueberry Vanilla',
        'qty' => '2'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Banana Strawberry',
        'qty' => '3'
    ]
];

$formatted = array_map( function($obj) {
    return "{$obj['name']} {$obj['qty']}"; 
}, $array );

echo implode( ', ', $formatted );
```

**[Example](http://ideone.com/QJ1sST)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {   

        $rray = array(
            'name'=>$item['name'],
            'qty'=>$item['qty']
        );
        $array[] = $rray; 

        }       


        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $result .= $value['name']." ". $value['qty'];       
            $result .= ", ";    
}
var_dump($result);
```

Work like a champ!